# How to save specific value in a field of DB in cakePHP 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to migrate CakePHP from 1.3 to 2.0. And now, I encounter a small problem regarding to inserting a value to a specific field. Here is the code in which I made in version 1.3:

```
function add() {

    if(isset($_SESSION['User']['id'])){ 
        if(!empty($this->data)) {
            if($this->Ad->save($this->data)){

                //saving the uID in table ads
                $this->data['Ad']['uID'] = $_SESSION['User']['id'];  
                $this->data['Ad']['DatePosted'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');     
                $this->data['Ad']['IP'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   
                $this->Ad->save($this->data, FALSE);                    

                $this->Session->setFlash('The post was successfully added!');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
            else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('The post was not saved. Please try again.', 'alert-message', array('class'=>'error'));
            }               
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->Session->setFlash('You have to login first to access control panel');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'));
    }   


    //for setting the category of advertisement
    $adcats = $this->Ad->Adcat->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','Description')));
    $this->set(compact('adcats'));

    //for setting the type of advertisement
    $adtyps = $this->Ad->Adtyp->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','Description')));
    $this->set(compact('adtyps'));  

}
```

Now, here is my code in which I want to include the user-ID (represents as uID), the post date (represents as DatePosted), and the IP address of the user.

```
public function add() {

    if($this->Session->read('user_id')){    
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Ad->save($this->request->data)){

                //saving the uID in table ads
                //$this->data['Ad']['uID'] = $this->Session->read('user_id');  
                //$this->data['Ad']['DatePosted'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');     
                //$this->data['Ad']['IP'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   

                $this->Ad->uID = $this->Session->read('user_id'); 
                $this->Ad->DatePosted = DboSource::expression('NOW()');
                $this->Ad->IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

                $this->Ad->save($this->request->data);                  

                $this->Session->setFlash('The post was successfully added!');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
            else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('The post was not saved. Please try again.', 'alert-message', array('class'=>'error'));
            }               
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->Session->setFlash('You have to login first to access control panel');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'));
    }   

    //for setting the category of advertisement
    $adcats = $this->Ad->Adcat->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','Description')));
    $this->set(compact('adcats'));

    //for setting the type of advertisement
    $adtyps = $this->Ad->Adtyp->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','Description')));
    $this->set(compact('adtyps'));  

}
```

Now, my question is how can I save those three fields that I mentioned it before?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->Session->read('user_id')){    
    if($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->request->data('Ad.uID', $this->Session->read('user_id'));
        $this->request->data('Ad.DatePosted', DboSource::expression('NOW()'));
        $this->request->data('Ad.IP', $this->request->clientIp());
        // or $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if($this->Ad->save($this->request->data)){

            $this->Session->setFlash('The post was successfully added!');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        // and so on
```

should do it.

> CakeRequest::data provides dot notation access to request data. Allows
>   for reading and modification of request data, calls can be chained
>   together as well

For future reference, if you have a field called `created` of `datetime` with a default value of `null`, Cake will auto-magically insert the record creation time - perhaps eliminating the need for `DatePosted`.

Comment: Thank you @Ross for your response. However, I have another question. What if I change the fieldname of DatePosted to created and you mentioned it that cake will auto-magically adds the created time of post, may I ask again the sample of code for this one? Actually, your codes that you provide is working, however only the DatePosted is not working, maybe or perhaps there is a required code that i need to include. Fatal error: Class 'DboSource' not found

Comment: not sure on that error - perhaps using `DboSource` changed in 2.0, can't find any documentation about it. Regarding the auto-magic, you simply need a field in your table that is called `created`, `modified` or `updated` (or all three), that is of `datetime` and a default value of `null`. Cake should do the rest - you don't even need to adjust any controller code.